# The difference of two define?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What the difference of two `define`?

```
#define NUM                 123
#define NUM_TO_STRING1(x)   #x
#define NUM_TO_STRING(x)    NUM_TO_STRING1(x)

printf("NUM_TO_STRING1: %s\n", NUM_TO_STRING1(NUM));
printf("NUM_TO_STRING:  %s\n", NUM_TO_STRING(NUM));
```

result:

```
NUM_TO_STRING1: NUM
NUM_TO_STRING:  123
```

Why `NUM_TO_STRIN1` can not change the `NUM` to string `123`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link:

[Stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

At the end it says:

> If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument, you have to use two levels of macros.

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
 str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
 xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4"
```

and read [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan) about order of Argument scanning in macros:

> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, **unless they are stringified or pasted with other tokens**. After substitution, the entire macro body, including the substituted arguments, is scanned again for macros to be expanded. The result is that the **arguments are scanned twice to expand macro calls** in them.

Comment: Basically your answer is not an answer qualified for SO, you are only giving links and not much explanation.

Answer (score 3):

With the `#`, you're asking it not to. All `#` does is to *stringify* the thing that immediately follows it. The idiom that I think you're trying to exploit is a common one:

```
#define STR(_a)   #_a
#define XSTR(_a)  STR(_a)

#define BAR foo
```

With things set up like this,

```
STR(BAR)
```

Will give you `"BAR"` and

```
XSTR(BAR)
```

Will give you `"foo"`

Comment: +1, but to make things clearer you could just append something like "since `BAR` is expanded before being passed to `STR`" ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

> NUM_TO_STRING1(NUM) becomes NUM

With #, NUM is stringified. Does not be replaced with 123.

> NUM_TO_STRING(NUM) becomes NUM_TO_STRING1(123)

123 is stringified, and the result is 123